# MFC Feature pack in Office 2010 style

Tags: mfc, ribbon, mfc-feature-pack, ribbon-control, office-2010

I developed app in mFC using vs2008 and MFC Feature pack 2008. its look and feel is like 2007 office style. Now i want app look and feel like office 2010.
Will you explain me how to do it?

Comment: **Some people are *never* happy.** Clue me in: what exactly is the difference? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the office 2007 the left side the circle appears, When click it open the File Types. But in the 2010 the File Tab is there. see the following LInk http://www.microsoft.com/business/en-us/products/Office2010Demo/Default.html#Video/OneNote/OneNote_MultipleContent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010, which provides a "Windows 7" style for the ribbon control. This style is supposed to simulate that *native* ribbon control that is used in Windows 7 applications like Paint and Wordpad. (Note that a slight modification to the wizard-generated code is currently necessary, as described [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551582/mfc-windows-7-ribbon-application-does-not-look-right) on Microsoft Connect.) Presumably, this style also looks like the one used in Office 2010, although I can't say for sure as I haven't given Microsoft *all* of my money yet.

Decide for yourself:

[image: Windows 7-style ribbon in VS 2010]

Alternatively, you could just use the native ribbon control yourself. There's a sample project here:
[Windows 7 Ribbon: The Time Has Come, Your Win32 Application Will Change](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/rib.aspx). But if you've already done a lot of work laying out the ribbon in VS 2008, this probably isn't a very compelling option.

Lesson: There's a hefty price to be paid for being on the bleeding edge. If this isn't *exactly* the same look that you're hoping to emulate, you may very well be out of luck. If your design goals amount to copying what the Office team does, you're going to be quite a busy little bee: toolbars are their absolute favorite thing to reinvent.

**EDIT:** Looks like you might not be *completely* out of luck after all. BCGSoft (the company that Microsoft bought the ribbon control from in the first place for the MFC Feature Pack) has released a library that [attempts to simulate the Office 2010 experience](http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour264.htm) in several different ways. Throw money at them [here](http://www.bcgsoft.com/bcgcontrolbarpro.htm).

[image: BCGControlBar with Office 2010-like interface]

Comment: I have one confusion 2010 look and feel is there in MFC feature pack 2008, or any other version

Comment: @Mahantesh: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I i use the MFC feature pack 2008 it will produce 2007 style window.. whether For 2010 style same feature pack i need to use with vs2010..?

Comment: @Mahantesh: I feel like I just explained all of that in my answer. There were even pretty pictures, but you still have to do a little reading. Upgrading to VS 2010 will get you a ribbon that looks like the first screenshot. Apparently that isn't *exactly* like the one in Office 2010, which comes as no surprise, since the Office team loves to reinvent toolbars. You will either have to wait until VS 2012 comes out and hope that it includes a ribbon control that looks more like the one in Office 2010, or buy a third-party control. I suggested one at the bottom; see the second screenshot.